# non-root user how to install docker?

Tags: docker, centos

I am using a CentOS 6.9 system of High performance computation platform and I wanna use docker with non-root user. Is there a method that I can build docker from source and do not need root privilege?

Comment: Docker doesn't really work without root. Maybe do the build in a VM where the root user is contained?

Comment: I suggest singularity (https://sylabs.io/singularity/).   Containers need to be built with root, but can run without it.  Be careful for any technology: CentOS 6 has old versions of the C library and ld loader.  So anything that requires libc > 2.12 won't run without a lot more work (or recompile)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This shouldn't be possible as it would be a major security concern.

When docker is installed on a machine, users with docker access (not necessarily root) can start containers. In particular, they can start containers in priviliged mode, giving the container access to all host devices.

More importantly, A user with access to docker can mount directories owned exclusively by machine root. Since by default, a root user inside the container will have access to mounted root-owned directories inside the container, this will allow any Docker container started by a non-root user to access critical machine stuff.

Therefore, the sequence of having a non-root user install Docker and start containers should not be allowed as it can compromise the whole machine.

Check this explicit [comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21351#issuecomment-198959417) from one of the docker maintainers.

Comment: well explained! I wish I could give more upvotes :-)

Comment: Thanks. I will try something else instead of using docker.

Comment: Why can't the access denied to non-root users be also be denied to the processes in the container? I feel this is more of an implementation issue rather than a vulnerability.

Comment: @VarunGarg The default behavior after installing Docker is that the us's uid inside the container maps to the same uid on the host. Thus by default user with uid `0` (root)  inside the container maps to root on host machine. To solve this issue, Docker introduced user namespaces(https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) that map container uids to a different range on host and thus avoiding the mention vulnerability. However, still installing Docker requires privileged access.

Answer (score 4):

Update to the yamenk's answer:
There is now an official rootless mode for Docker: [Run the Docker daemon as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#prerequisites)
Here's an explanation of how it works from one of Docker engineers:
[Experimenting with Rootless Docker](https://www.docker.com/blog/experimenting-with-rootless-docker/)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I think a nicer answer would be to summarize your findings and explain exactly what it offers in context of the question (and accepted answer).

Comment: Do we need root to install 'rootless' docker?